# Restaurant System database/text files

Tags: c#, sql, text

I have a yearly project due for next week that iv been working on,  it's a restaurant /cafe point of sale system as an assignment to integrate everything we have learnt in c# so far.

I'm stuck on a small problem I have a database of ingredients (like cheese tomatoes....)  and waiters I'd with username and what not. My problem comes in that I want to make a new order so an order is created and the customers items they ordered are added I just don't know how do I go about the following:

1. Continuing a order?  The waiter places an initial order for the customers but how do I get the waiter who logs back in a later stage to see her active orders and then edit/add to those orders?  I had the idea of creating a text file then at the end of the whole text file and once the order is closed to then edit all the items sold and the materials used to sell them from the database?  But then there is no way to check if for example cheese is in Stock before they order a burger?

I basically want to be able to continue a order of the active waiter who is logged in and still be able to void any faults / check stock at the same time too.

It's a project for myself so no homework related or such I'm just stuck on how to overcome this.

Comment: This is more of DB question then a C# question.
You need to break your problem ( think requests) into chunks to implement.

Comment: Why use a text file, put in the db?

Comment: How can i add code to a project that i need help with? I didnt ask for help in code format and i just needed guidance on the problem. Please think before marking my question down to be put on hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't much technical details in your question so here comes a general awnser :)

First of all, don't use text files. If you have a database, use that to store all your data.

Lets say you have the following tables, `Dishes` `Orders` `Waiters` and `ingredients`
in order to relate these you will have a number of ["join tables"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), `IngredientsInDish`, `DishesInOrder` and so on. Lets also say that `Orders` have a Column for `Waiter` (a foreign key)

So now lets say you want to add dishes for an order created by the waiter `Bob`

You'd first look up `Bobs` id from the `Waiters` table, then find his orders from the `Orders` table using `Bobs` id. Then you'd find the Order to add a dish to, and insert a new row in the `DishesInOrder` table providing the order id and the dish id or the new dish (You'd have to find that first as well)

If you want to verify that all the ingredients are available, you should do that before inserting into the `DishesInOrder` table. you'd probably have the waiter select a dish, then look in the `IngredientsInDish` table for the ingredients and check their availability in the `Ingredients` table first. if they are all there, the waiter is allowed to add the dish to the order as escribed above. At that time you could also subtract the ingredients from the stock in the `Ingredients` table

You can also have a column in `Order` that shows If a order is submitted. When you're calculating the stock for items you can look though all the submitted orders (limited to the current day perhaps) You could then check for ingredient availability before adding dishes as described above.

Comment: Sorry about the general answer I'm on the move so on my phone. That sounds like a lot simpler idea and time saving too.  I suppose adding another table to check if the order is complete or not would work too. When the waiter ie Bob continues the order I could then manipulate the database entry to output into a visual text box for example slip printing reasons. Wow I didn't think of it that way and Thank you for that assistance I was confusing myself with text files and seeing a more practical implementation like the above is really of great help.  Thanks you @aL3891

Comment: I managed to make a quick table for Usernames(Basically the waiters/login details) that links to the Orders table via a relationship this is working all cool, Im able to create a new order related to the username/waiter in question too. From there how do i 
use the database to "record" what meals they have chosen so far in order to effectively create a bill/slip for the customer to pay later on? The orders are all recorded because a "feature" of my program allows a manager to print reports on orders made and what not.

Comment: I have removed the ingredients table, and added a Dishes table with the dish in question and how much "stock" i have of that dish for quantity purposes.For example "Savory Muffin" i have "50 servings. So basically all ill need to do now is check the servings and deduct a serving after that and somehow record what waiter ordered what serving. 
Small work but it includes the SQL commands that we will be tested on so its enough.

Comment: you need to use a join table, see my response :) if you need more information, open a new question and I'm sure people will help you out :)